# PDF readers not based on poppler?

Tags: pdf, software-rec, alternatives, poppler

It seems that most GNU/Linux PDF readers use [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) for rendering.

For testing purposes I would like **not** to use poppler.  Are there any (recent) alternatives ?

`xpdf` doesn't count, since I expect both to share large pieces of code.

Comment: You might try the online viewers, like [pdfescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/) (limited size), or a Windows viewer under wine like [foxit](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) (which seems to now have a Linux version).  Chrome has a built-in viewer too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mupdf](http://mupdf.com/) for example is not based on poppler.

Comment: MuPDF is based on GhostScript.  Poppler is the successor on Xpdf, which is also based on GhostScript.  Welcome to the Brave New World, where an Adobe format invented in 1990's for marketing reasons is an ISO standard, and its description takes 1200 pages.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Well, PDF is based on PostScript, so it makes sense to base a PDF reader on an existing PostScript implementation ... (is there any other open source one besides GhostScript?)

Comment: Not that I know of, and I don't expect any new one to pop up any time soon, simply because of the complexity of the format.  Something similar can also be observed for commercial implementations, where everybody licenses code from Adobe.  About a year ago there was a bug in Acrobat reader for mobiles, and just about all other mobile PDF readers were also affected.  FWIW, the first versions of PDF were just PostScript with checksums.